# moodle manage classrooms reservation

Tags: moodle

we want to expand moodle by creating a classroom reservation module, so the users can reserve an specific time and clasroom to atend.

However we never did anything to moodle so we don't really know how hard would it be of it is possible,

Any advice would be really appreciated

Comment: Your question is way too unspecific, basically asking for a tutorial and in general not a good fit for the Q&A format of SO. Please read a book/tutorial/whatever you like and familiarize yourself with moodle and come back with _specific_ problems you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need the facetoface module. Its widely used and well maintained. I used to work with the developer ;)

https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=mod_facetoface